# Frate Rate for android video recording application - Required around 30 frames per second ..!

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, frame-rate

Following is th code which helps in capturing the video but the problem is with the frame rate as i have already defined framerate to 30 frames per sec still. When record a video using front camera its gives an output of 8 frames per sec and with back camera it give max 15 to 18 frames

```
private void startRecording() {

    if(mrec != null){
        mrec.reset();   
    }

    mCamera.unlock();
    mrec.setCamera(mCamera);
    mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mrec.setVideoSize(640, 480);
    mrec.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
    mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);// MPEG_4_SP

    File dir = new File(SdCardPath + Directory);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        if (dir.mkdir()) {
            Log.v(STORAGE_SERVICE, "Created directory");
        } else {
            Log.v(STORAGE_SERVICE, "Failed to create Directory");
        }
    }

    FullFilePath = SdCardPath + Directory + RecordFileName;

    mrec.setOutputFile(FullFilePath);
    mrec.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
    try {
        mrec.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mrec.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to android documentation

```
mrec.setVideoFrameRate(30);
```

may not work as you are expecting it to work. If your device cannot give you 30 frames per second, then there will be some internal clipping, and the frame rate will be set to the maximum frame rate that the device supports.

Also, in practise, I have observed, that even for legitimate values, the setVideoFrameRate() call is not reliable, and the actual frame rate may differ from the value that you pass to this function.

Comment: i agree with u `mrec.setVideoFrameRate(30);` was not working . Then added tried following code in surfaceCreated() function .

        `Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
 p.setPreviewFrameRate(29);            
        p.setPreviewFpsRange(24000,29000);
 p.setPreviewSize(640, 480);
 mCamera.setParameters(p);`

This is working fine on android 2.3.3 but the app crashes in above versions . !! any idea ??

Comment: After gingerbread version, the way to access the camera is through a different API. In your code, you should check if the built version is gingerbread or higher, and access the camera using a separate mechanism. See http://digitaldumptruck.jotabout.com/?p=797 for some code.